# How to populate text in a different language into an SQLite Database for Android Developement?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

i'm planning on creating an app for android that reads another language from an sqlite database. The first challenge i'm trying to solve is how to actually put the different lanugage, which is Twi/Akan (ghanian language),into the sqlite db.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite always uses Unicode (encoded in UTF-8).

Whatever characters you put into the database will be the same when you pull them out of it later.